# Создание своего хелпера (Helper) в Zend Framework 3 (Не получается)

Tags: zend-framework-3

Доброе!
Создал класс в /module/Application/src/View/Helper/Messages

Код:

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

// Этот класс помощника отображения разных сообщений пользователю (статичных)
class Messages extends AbstractHelper { 
public function __construct() {   
}   
protected function renderErrorMessages($item) {
        echo "!!!";
}

}
```

Добавил его в настройки модуля:

Код:

```
  ....
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,                       
            Controller\UserController::class => InvokableFactory::class,                       
        ],
    ],
    'view_helpers' => [
            'factories' => [
                View\Helper\Messages::class => InvokableFactory::class,                   
            ],
           'aliases' => [
                'messages' => View\Helper\Messages::class
           ]
        ],                   
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
```

....

На странице login.phtml пытаюсь вставить :

Код:

```
...
<?php echo $this->Messages()->renderErrorMessages(); ?>
...
```

Получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> [Wed Mar 13 12:18:30.725622 2019] [php7:error] [pid 9697] [client
>   127.0.0.1:52914] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: A plugin by
>   the name "Messages" was not found in the plugin manager
>   Zend\View\HelperPluginManager in
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php:142\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(376):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Messages', NULL)\n#1
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(394):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->plugin('Messages')\n#2
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/module/Application/view/layout/login.phtml(32):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('Messages', Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(506):
>   include('/var/www/webuse...')\n#4
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(207):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(NULL)\n#5
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrateg
>   in
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php
>   on line 142, referer: http://127.0.0.128/user/login
>       1

Подскажите, где туплю?

Answer (score 0):

Cлепой (с). Сразу несколько ошибок было:
Правильно: в /module/Application/src/View/Helper/Messages

```
public function renderErrorMessages() {
echo "!!!";
}
```

- вместо public - protected и renderErrorMessages без параметра..